# unable to start Alfresco 3.4.4 (Error while starting postgresql)

Tags: database, linux, postgresql, alfresco

I am using Alfresco 3.4.4 in my production environment(Redhat Linux). Yesterday I just tried to restart my Alfresco server but now it's not starting up. The tomcat starts successfully but postgres throws an exception while starting the server (here I am using postgres DB that was bundled with alfresco and haven't modified anything in the configuration files).
 I manually tried to start the postgresql server from alfresco/postgresql/scripts/ctl.sh and got the following error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

Then I executed the following commands (I found this solution somewhere on the net):

> $ cd /postgresql/bin
>
> $ . setenv.sh
>
> $ ldd initdb.bin

After executing these commands I didn't get any error related to libssl.so but still I am not able to start the Postgres server and I only get the following error:

> ./ctl.sh : postgresql  could not be started

Edit: ldd command gives the following output:

> linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4251e000)
>           libssl.so.0.9.8 => /opt/alfresco-3.4.4/common/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0x00002b2e2c607000)
>           libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /opt/alfresco-3.4.4/common/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0x00002b2e2c755000)
>           libz.so.1 => /opt/alfresco-3.4.4/common/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00002b2e2c9cb000)
>           libreadline.so.5 => /opt/alfresco-3.4.4/common/lib/libreadline.so.5 (0x00002b2e2cae5000)
>           libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x000000338a200000)
>           libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003377c00000)
>           libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003377400000)
>           libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003377000000)
>           /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003376c00000)

Comment: Have you got that version of libssl installed? Have you perhaps done an openssl upgrade recently?

Comment: Yes libssl is present under alfresco-3.4.4/common/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8 and no I have not upgraded openssl.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ldd postmaster` (run from within the bin directory)?

Comment: added the output above.

Comment: That looks fine. Do any postgres logs get generated which explain why it couldn't start? Or failing that, what about if you try to run postmaster by hand?

Comment: well the problem seems to be resolved now..there was an issue with postgresql.pid
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and found the solution.

You have to do these commands in the /postgresql/bin directory of alfresco :

```
$ . setenv.sh
$ ldd initdb.bin
```

And after that (I think your problem is here now), stop the postgresql database, and alfresco :

```
$ service postgresql stop
$ sh /opt/alfresco.../alfresco.sh stop
```

Then start Alfresco :

```
$ sh /opt/alfresco.../alfresco.sh start
```

Then if you restart alfresco or your server, you might need to stop the postgresql service and alfresco and then start alfresco.

Your problem is already resolved but it can help someone else who will have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly this shows how unhelpful the messages of wrapper scripts can be.  You may want to note for future cases that it is worth checking PostgreSQL server logs for startup failure reasons.

In your case what probably happened was that you had an unclean shutdown and the postmaster.pid was left around.  This didn't get cleaned up by your startup script and so PostgreSQL thought it might already be running and so refused to start.